# mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) vs SHOW TABLE STATUS for row count

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We have a table in our database that has teens of millions of entries (10.1.21-MariaDB; InnoDB table engine; Windows OS).  We are able to get the number of rows in the table instantaneously using the command `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'my_table_name'`.  However, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table_name` takes a few minutes to complete.

---

Q) Why is `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'my_table_name'` so so much quicker than `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table_name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because one is a query that counts all the rows and the other is a command that retrieves stats the DB engine maintains about the table. There isn't any firm guarantee that the table statistic will be up to date so the only way to get an accurate count is to count the rows, but it might be that you don't need it to be perfectly accurate all the time. You can thus choose either, depending on your desire for accuracy vs speed etc.

See here this screenshot from https://pingcap.com/docs/stable/sql-statements/sql-statement-show-table-status/

[image]

You can see the example inserts 5 rows but the table stats are out of date and the table still reports 0 rows. Running ANALYZE TABLE will (probably) take longer than counting the rows, but the stats will be up to date (for a while at least) afterwards.

Comment: `ANALYZE` is fast, but not accurate.  Only `COUNT(*)` is guaranteed to give you the exact count.

Answer (score 1):

A suggested approach to get a reasonably accurate count of the table size, when `SELECT COUNT(*)` is taking a long time to complete, could be:
`ANALYZE TABLE my_table_name; SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'my_table_name';`

This comes in especially handy when importing a large amount of data into a table, and you want to track the progress of the import process.